# Formulário em Flask não funciona

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Quando eu clico no botão para Enviar nada acontece, se deixo um campo em branco, idem.

Arquivo routes.py

```
from flask import *
from forms import *
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('homepage.html', title='Home')#, 404

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')

@app.route('/subscription', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('User %s logged in!' % form.user.data)
        return redirect('/home')
    return render_template('signup.html', title='Sign Up', form=form)

@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html', title='Contact')

@app.route('/turma')
def turma():
    return render_template('turminha.html', title='Turma')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config.update({'SECRET_KEY': 'guess-it', 'WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY': 'guess-it'})
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Arquivo forms.py:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import *
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    """docstring for LoginForm"""
    user = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    passw = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

Arquivo signup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>GahioGames - {{title}}</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/InscriçãoCSS.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="static/img/fallout.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body ng-app='entra'>
    <ul id="topo">
        <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
        <li class="drop">
            <a href="assuntos.html" class="drop">Assuntos</a>
            <div class="cont">
                <a href="#">Redes</a>
                <a href="#">Hardware</a>
                <a href="#">Software</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="inscrição.html"><b>Inscreva-se</b></a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <h1>INSCREVA-SE</h1>
    <article>
        <h4>Para saber de todas nossas novidades!!!</h4>
        <form autocomplete="on" name="formula" method="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <p> {{ form.user.label }} {{ form.user(size=32) }} </p>
            {% for error in form.user.errors %}
            <p style="color: red;"> {{ error }} </p>
            {% endfor %}

            <p> {{ form.passw.label }} {{ form.passw(size=16) }} </p>
            {% for error in form.passw.errors %}
            <p style="color: red;"> {{ error }} </p>
            {% endfor %}

            <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
                <!--<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome:" required>
                <br>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:" required ng-model='txt'><p ng-show='formula.email.$error.email'>E-mail inválido</p>
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha:" required>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="verde"><a href="mailto: someone@gmail.com?Subject=Ola Pessoa" target='_top'>Enviar</a></button>
                <button type="reset" class="red">Limpar</button>-->
        </form>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
        <ul>
            {% for msg in messages %}
            <li>{{ msg }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <h4>Visite nossas outras páginas também!!!</h4>
        <a href="https://facebook.com" class="ico"><span class="fa fa-facebook-square"></span></a>
        <a href="https://store.steampowered.com" class="ico"><span class="fa fa-steam-square"></span></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com" class="ico"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
    </article>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('entra', []);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não deveria ter um atributo `action` no seu formulário?

Comment: Quando não há um action definido ele posta para a mesma url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvido, havia um problema com um angularJS escondido...